# How to implement Open Sans Web Font in Outlook?

Tags: html, css, asp.net, webfonts

I am trying to add the Open Sans font to a HTML email but In outlook 2007/2013 Arial font is displaying.
Following is my code:

```
     <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,300,700'rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'/>

 <style type="text/css">

    @media screen{
       .webfont {
         font-family: 'Open Sans', Arial, sans-serif !important;
  }
 }
</style>
```

Web Font class is passing to Div with Style option  (
    div class="webfont" style="width: 620px; padding: 0 14px; border: 1px solid #dcdcdc; margin: 0 auto;font: normal 15px ; color: #555;">)

Comment: Web fonts only works wit apple mail - https://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/

Comment: there is no other option to work with MS outlook?

Comment: Check this, see if works for you - http://blog.postup.com/outlook-fix-for-using-webfonts-in-your-email

Comment: I tried it but its not working . I am using  Outlook 2013

Answer (score 1):

Most web fronts don't work in Outlook 2013. I believe Times New Roman is the only approved web font. [**There's a chart here**](http://blog.postup.com/using-web-fonts-in-email) showing which email clients accept web fonts.